# jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

My application uses Servlet 5.0 and JSP. Everything was fine as long as I used the url template `urlPatterns = {"/sample"}` (without (*)) and was catching this url `/sample?col=20`

but when i changed it `urlPatterns = {"/sample/*"}` and changed the url `/sample/Tom-Sawyer?col=20`
I get exception "Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20"

My Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "Sample",  urlPatterns = {"/sample/*"})
public class SampleController extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        long col =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("col"));

    ... some Business logic ...

       RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/sample.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Possible conflict with my filter

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "EndsWith", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class TypeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/book")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/book").forward(request, response);
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a slash before the WEB-INF `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/sample.jsp"`

Strange, if the pattern is like `urlPatterns = {"/sample"}` it works without a slash `request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/sample.jsp"`